# How to add a filter for commnets title in Wordpress facebook plugin

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, title

I am not a pro in wordpress hooks and filters and therefore anyone expert can help me in creating a filter for a facebook wordpress plugin so that it shows the comments title on site.

the plugin url is

http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/facebook

```
and here is the documentation about how to get this solved...
```

facebook_wp_comments_title

The Facebook plugin for WordPress implementation of the Comments Box social plugin     overrides your WordPress theme's comments template including the displayed title of the     comments section. Act on the string value passed to this filter to affect the inner text of     h2.comments-title inside the custom comments template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the `facebook_wp_comments_title` filter like this:

```
function my_custom_filter( $title ) {
    $title = 'Your title goes here';
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'facebook_wp_comments_title', 'my_custom_filter' );
```

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter

Comment: Sorry, but this did not solve the issue.
See  http://yogamoo.com/abu/week-27-yogamoo-roundup/

Comment: You asked how to add a filter for the 'commnets' title using `facebook_wp_comments_title`. That's how you use the filter.